# How to insert some text in middle of file in PHP

Tags: php, file

How to insert some text middle of the file in php,
is that ay method available to insert text in middle of file content.

not exactly middle of the file.,
search a keyword, then we need to insert before or after the content,

if the search keyword found more than one time in file, then wat would be happen

Comment: Your question is difficult to understand and provides no context. Can you explain what you are trying to do, and what you actually mean by 'insert text'?

Comment: Your question is unclear and not thoroughly researched.  This information is available on php.net, and very easy to find.

Comment: +1 Because researching the question lead me to discovering the `fseek()` function for the first time in my career ;)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using [`fopen`](http://php.net/fopen), [`fseek`](http://php.net/fseek), [`ftell`](http://php.net/ftell), [`fwrite`](http://php.net/fwrite), and [`fclose`](http://php.net/fclose):

```
// Create the file handler
$file = fopen("filename", "r+");
// Seek to the end
fseek($file, SEEK_END, 0);
// Get and save that position
$filesize = ftell($file);
// Seek to half the length of the file
fseek($file, SEEK_SET, $filesize / 2);
// Write your data
fwrite($file, "Data");
// Close the file handler
fclose($file);
```

Comment: +1 for being precisely in the middle of the file. (I'd give another +1 if you took the new content's length in to consideration, however)

Comment: +1 cuz everyone else did? Very simple answer

Comment: i just want to search a date inside the file content, then insert after that,

Answer (score 6):

- [`fopen()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php)
- **[`fseek()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fseek.php)** <-- What you want I'd imagine
- [`fwrite()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php)
- [`fclose()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fclose.php)

Answer (score 6):

1. open source file
2. open new destination file
3. copy "first part" of source file into destination file
4. add new content to destination file
5. copy "last part" of source file into destination file
6. close both files
7. delete original file
8. rename new file

Comment: +1 for tuiting that "insert some text in the middle of a file" doesn't mean "overwrite what's there" but "insert a new line."

Answer (score 2):

fopen, then fseek, then fwrite