# PHP: how to write in between content of existing file?

Tags: php

How to write in between content of existing file?

I tried to use fseek() to seek a new position and write the new content, but it replaces old content to the new string after seek position.

My aim is to put new contents after 5 characters of existing file.

Old content: `AAAAABBBBB`, desired content: `AAAAAnewcontentBBBBB`

```
$file_handler = fopen('putty.log','w');
$new_content = 'this is new content';

fseek($file_handler,5);

echo ftell($file_handler); //5
fwrite($file_handler,$new_content);
```

old content replaced with `NULLNULLNULLNULLNULLthis is new content`

Comment: Link http://stackoverflow.com/q/6472408/1338846

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it that way.

You can only truncate the content with **ftruncate** and write later the old content

A not so clean example

```
<?php

$file_handler = fopen('putty.log','rb+');
$new_content = 'this is new content';

fseek($file_handler,5);

$restOfContent = fread($file_handler,filesize('putty.log')-5);

ftruncate($file_handler,5);
fseek($file_handler,5);

echo ftell($file_handler); //5
fwrite($file_handler,$new_content);

fwrite($file_handler,$restOfContent);

fclose($file_handler)
```

Comment: don't we need to rewind() after fread($file_handler,filesize('putty.log')-5);? or after reading EOF if we seek again it starts from beginning?

Comment: i think when file pointer reaches EOF and i seek again, it starts from 0.

Answer (score 1):

1. Load contents to variable using file_get_contents().
2. Do this on your buffer.
3. Save your contents to this file using file_put_contents();

Comment: yup that's memory burden if file is huge.

Comment: yes but fastest development ;-) think about how code will be used in lifetime, because maybe this can be better solution in relation to your time what you spend on that

Answer (score 1):

if you're using fseek() to write data to a file, remember to open the file in "r+"
mode, example:

> $fp=fopen($filename,"r+");

Comment: thanks, i guess w mode always truncate file to zero length in beginning.

Comment: w actually overwrites the existing file.

Answer (score 1):

Writing in the middle of the file won't cause it to stretch and push the content forward (like when inserting content in a text editor) but rather to overwrite the content at the position you start writing.
What you need to do is:

1. read the first part of the old data until the point where you need to write the new content & write that part to a temporary file.
2. write the new content to the temporary file (the stuff you wish to add).
3. read the rest of the content from the old file & write it to the temporary file.
4. delete the old file.
5. rename the temporary file to the name of the old file.

Example:

```
$original_file_name = '/tmp/putty.log';
$temp_file_name = '/tmp/putty.tmp';
$temp_file = fopen( $temp_file_name, 'w' );
$file_handler = fopen( $original_file_name, 'r' );
$old_data_size = 5;
fwrite( $temp_file, fread( $file_handler, $old_data_size ) );
$new_content = 'this is new content';
fwrite( $temp_file, $new_content, strlen( $new_content ) );
fwrite( $temp_file, fread( $file_handler, filesize( $original_file_name ) - $old_data_size ) );
fclose( $file_handler );
fclose( $temp_file );
unlink( $original_file_name );
rename( $temp_file_name, $original_file_name );
```

Make sure that putty.log has read/write permissions for the user used by your webserver (apache/lighttpd etc.) process or that it's accessible for everyone (not recommended).