# PHP : Insert content in between specific line of a file?

Tags: php, file

Imagine I have a TXT file (some.txt) with the following contents:

```
data of first line
data of next line
#start-marker

data of next line
#end-marker
data of next line
```

And I want to write some lines just after #start-marker

Currently, I have this:

```
$fp = fopen('some.txt','r+');
$insertPos=0;
while (!feof($fp)) {
    $line=fgets($fp);
    if (strpos($line, '#start-marker')!==false) {
        $insertPos=ftell($fp);
}
fseek($fp,$insertPos);
fwrite($fp,'Data to be written');
fclose($fp);
```

But, the problem is :

```
data of first line
data of next line
#start-marker
Data to be written
```

All lines are disappear after new inserted line.

How to do this ?

Expected Output :

```
data of first line
data of next line
#start-marker

Data to be written
data of next line
#end-marker
data of next line
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/6472446/689579

Answer (score 0):

```
$myfile = file_get_contents('some.txt');
$insert = '#start-marker blah blah blah new data here';
$myfile = str_replace('#start-marker', $insert, $myfile, 1);
file_put_contents('some.txt', $myfile);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for append to file.
Try change from 'r+' into adding mode `a+` to your code:

```
$fp = fopen('some.txt','a+');
$insertPos=0;
while (!feof($fp)) {
    $line=fgets($fp);
    if (strpos($line, '#start-marker')!==false) {
        $insertPos=ftell($fp);
}
fseek($fp,$insertPos);
fwrite($fp,'Data to be written');
fclose($fp);
```

Reference: mode parameter- http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php

Comment: still will overwrite the data?

Comment: with use of a+ , only append at last, not in between

Comment: oh i see, i thought you want to append at end of file.
try this see whether work or not remain as r+ only, change fseek($fp,$insertPos); into fseek($fp,SEEK_SET,$insertPos);

Answer (score 0):

Looking for js code injection to file using php check the below code use js file or file path to append the code

```
<?php 
$jsFile = '';
 $fileLines = file($jsFile);

$Line1 = 10; 
$Line2 = 20;
$Code1 = "js code for line 10";
$Code2 = "js code for line 20";
array_splice($fileLines, $Line1 - 1, 0, $Code1);
array_splice($fileLines, $Line2 - 1, 0, $Code2);

file_put_contents($jsFile, implode('', $fileLines));
?>
```